# Node: compute "cumulative" total

Tags: arrays, node.js, loops

I have this data structure where each object in an array comes with a number - a "num" property in my case. So- Is there an easier way in node (than what I did below) to compute a number for each object that is the value of all of the numbers it's parent array that came before it?

```
_ = require('underscore');

_.nst = require('underscore.nest');

var data = [
    {'name' : 'name 1', 'num' : 40},
    {'name' : 'name 1', 'num' : 20},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 10},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 50},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 40},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 70},
    {'name' : 'name 2', 'num' : 30}
];
```

this gives me an array of 2 arrays

```
var obj = _.chain(data)
       .groupBy('name')
       .map(function ( value) {
          return _.sortBy(value, 'num');
       }).value();
```

Is there an easier way to do this other than a long for loop thats inside another loop (each)?.. For each object I need to get the total values of the objects that came before it or 0 in the case of the first object?...

```
_.each(obj, function(value){ 
  //loop through each array in obj
  for(var i=0; i<value.length; i++){
    if (i !== 0 && i > 1) {
      value[i].basis = value[i].num + value[i-1].basis;
    } else if (i === 1) {
      value[i].basis = value[i].num + value[i-1].num;
    } else {
      value[i].basis = 0;
    }
  }
});

console.log(obj);
```

...to get this:
[image]

Comment: The first number per name in your output seems to be wrong. Anyways it's easiest to improve if you change your data structure where you save the values. Where does the data come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using reduce. (When it comes to accumulating a value in a loop, reduce is often a good idea.)

```
_.each(obj, function(subArr){
  _.reduce(subArr, function(total, currentObj) {
    return currentObj.basis = (total += currentObj.num); 
  }, 0);
});
```

I'm sure there are cleverer solutions, but with the subarrays I don't think you can get away without using a forEach, atleast not without making things needlessly complex.